# Can I conditionally apply style from a function inline?

Tags: reactjs

When `ZoomedIn` is true, `this.state.transform[ref]` is always defined. I wish to only run `zoomIn` if the `zoomedIn` is true. Here is my function now:

```
  zoomedIn () {
    return ['zoomIn', 'addBg', 'zoom', 'removeBg'].includes(this.props.zoom)
  }
  zoomIn (ref) {
    if (this.zoomedIn()) {
      const transform = this.state.transform[ref]
      if (transform.scale > 1.1) {
        return {
          transform: 'translateY(' + transform.offset + 'px) scale(' + transform.scale + ')'
        }
      }
    }
  }

  <div ref='carousel'
    className='carousel' style={{
      ...this.zoomIn('carousel')
    }}
>
```

I have tried to do this instead, but it complains that state.transform is not defined.

```
  zoomedIn () {
    return ['zoomIn', 'addBg', 'zoom', 'removeBg'].includes(this.props.zoom)
  }
  zoomIn (ref) {
      const transform = this.state.transform[ref]
      if (transform.scale > 1.1) {
        return {
          transform: 'translateY(' + transform.offset + 'px) scale(' + transform.scale + ')'
        }
      }
   }

  <div ref='carousel' className='carousel' style={{
      ...this.zoomedIn() && this.zoomIn('carousel')
    }}
>
```

Comment: Did you bind zoomIn to the current component scope?

Comment: @Pineda how would I do that and also execute the function?

Comment: You can achieve what you need by conditionally rendering JSX based on the value returned by zoomedIn as per my answer below :)

Comment: You can bind a component method of a ReactJS  component in the constructor as follows: this.functionName = this.functionName.bind(this)

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render different JSX given the value of zoomedIn:

```
if(zoomedIn()){
  // you know this.state.transform exists here:
  const transform = this.state.transform[ref]
  if (transform.scale > 1.1) {
    return <div 
               ref='carousel'
               className='carousel'
               style={{ 'translateY(' + transform.offset + 'px) scale(' + transform.scale + ')' }}
            />
  }else{
    return <div ref='carousel' className='carousel' />;
  }
}else{
  return <div ref='carousel' className='carousel' />;
}
```